# SQL Server 2012 - Is use of cursor/dynamicSQL combo good practice?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, cursor

Most common answers are: **NO, don't use cursors, don't use dynamic SQL**

But this question is to solicit feedback from a coding style that seems nifty but can be bad practice, heavier processing speeds, and SQL injections(?).

I learned this style due to an annoyance with copy-pasting set queries of which only one or two items change between each query.  I find this style easier to perform code-reviews due to having only one code block, removing the need to scroll up and down.

**An example use case is:** a big slow table with historical data from 20 different insurance companies that is 1.7 billion rows by 200 columns. To do productive analysis, 10 columns are retrieved into separate tables for each of the 20 insurance companies.

**Before** the cursor/dynamic combination, a query was built and code-reviewed for one plan, then copied 19 times, each time retrieving a different plan.

**After** utilizing cursor/dynamic combo, there is one 20 item cursor and one dynamic SQL block. Review wise, it seems more consistent and less prone to human error.

A code example of the combo is below:

```
Declare @company_name varchar(10)
       ,@SQL_STATEMENT varchar(100)

Declare company_cursor cursor fast_forward for  (
SELECT * FROM (VALUES('APPLE'),('GOOGLE'),('AMAZON')) AS TABLE_NAME(COLUMN_NAME)
)

open company_cursor
fetch next from company_cursor into @company_name

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    set @SQL_STATEMENT = 'select * from database.schema.'+@company_name
    print (@SQL_STATEMENT)
    fetch next from company_cursor into @company_name 
end 
close company_cursor 
deallocate company_cursor
```

I also noticed using a PRINT instead of EXEC instantaneously prints the query statement and acts as a code generator if the PRINT results are copied into the SQL editor.

Can somebody offer opinions, advice, or general practice rules surrounding this style of T-SQL coding? (bracing for downvotes...sniff)

Comment: Well, if the `APPLE`, `GOOGLE` and `AMAZON` tables all have the same structure, I would say that the worst problem here is that the database design is wrong, and the companies all need to be on a single table, with a column for company name (or id), instead of having a duplicate table for each company. If that is not the case, then cursor and dynamic SQL doesn't seem like a bad choice for this. Sometimes you must do the quick and dirty.

Comment: I should have clarified that the example code is more of a template to describe the cursor/dynamicSQL combo.  I use it whenever I need to run the same query multiple times where each run points to a different table or one/two WHERE clause changes.  
The use case is a real business scenario:  due to forces out of my control, we have a gigantic table that is so large that indexes are limited and exploratory analysis is near impossible.  To workaround this, we take about 10 of the 200 columns and create 20 tables, one for each insurance plan.  Two items change between queries:  table name and ID